# How to combine SUBTOTAL and SUMIFS in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]

I am struggling to combine my SUMIFS formula with SUBTOTAL. As you can see in the picture, my SUMIFS formula (highlighted in yellow, formulate pasted as text below it) sums up Column C when values in Column B are above 50 and below 500.

How can I write a SUBTOTAL formula such that it will only sum Column C values WHEN Column B values are above 50 and below 500, AND are ONLY in Category A ONLY (orange, formula pasted as text below it)?

Two formulas: 
=SUMIFS(C8:C25,B8:B25,"<"&B2,B8:B25,">"&B1)
=SUBTOTAL(109,C8:C25)

Comment: What exactly does your Subtotal formula do with regards to Category A??

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition to the SumIfs formula

```
 =SUMIFS(C8:C25,B8:B25,"<"&B2,B8:B25,">"&B1,A8:A25,"A")
```

Or use another cell reference instead of the text "A".

Answer (score 0):

You could try the formula, but it seems too long ：

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($A$8,ROW($A$8:$A$25)-8,))*($A$8:$A$25="A")*($B$8:$B$25<$B$2)*($B$8:$B$25>$B$1)*($C$8:$C$25))
```

Then the result will change after filter.

Answer (score 0):

*SUBTOTAL is required when you filter the data set, otherwise what you are trying to achieve is possible by using SUMPRODUCT also:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter criteria in cell D16 & E16.
- Apply Data Validation on cell F16.
- Use List and add A, B, C, D & Blank.
- Formula in cell G16:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(F16),"",SUMPRODUCT((A17:A32=F$16)*(B17:B32<E$16)*(B17:B32>D$16)*(C17:C32)))
  ```
- Formula in cell C36:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(F16),"",SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C17:C32,ROW(C17:C32)-ROW(C17),0,1,1)),--(B17:B32>D16)))
  ```
- Now select A16:C32 and apply Filter for Category B.
- Select category B from Drop down in F16.

*You find both formula produces same result.*

[image]

*Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer to this. But just in case anyone else is trying to figure this out, this is the formula I ended up using.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(C$8:C25,ROW(C$8:C25)-MIN(ROW(C$8:C25)),,1)),--($B$8:$B25>B1),--($B$8:$B25